# Why does the current waveform become non-linear in a bridge rectifier?

Tags: current, ac, non-linear

This is my bridge rectifier circuit, and I'm trying to understand why the current waveform of the source deforms the way it does when you approach an ideal capacitor. Source V1 is 9VAC.

[image]

I simulated the current through V1 for capacitor C1 values from 10uF to 1F, and the current waveform changes from a sinusoidal to a very peaky deformed waveform

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is a zoomed in trace of the waveforms. The light blue difference between line voltage and voltage at the capacitor:

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what for is R2? Especially that it's 0.5 Ohm.

Comment: @MikeSpark Ah sorry, left that in from before. Thought I'd add some losses to see if I could understand it better

Answer (score 1):

Current can only flow from the utility (the ac network) to your circuit if the voltage is higher that the voltage on the capacitor.

With no capacitance the output voltage follows the rectified ac and thus the current also follows this (for a resistive load)

As you start adding capacitance to your circuit it is providing "holdup" which creates a flatter, more DC rail. The periods where the AC is higher than your DC become smaller and smaller.

As a result the peak current that needs to flow increases to ensure a consistent amp-seconds to the capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this: -

[image]

The blue trace is the voltage on the output capacitor - notice that it slowly droops when the red trace drops away - this is due to output load current discharging the capacitor between AC cycles.

To replenish that charge, the red trace can only do this when it reaches a slightly higher voltage than the blue trace. Normally, this only occurs at the peak of the red trace - at all other times the diodes in the bridge remain reverse biased and pass little or no current.

At that peak of the cycle, the current draw through the bridge rises rapidly to a peak. As soon as the red trace starts to fall, no more charging current is taken thus, the current waveform is how you picture them in your question.

Comment: I edited my question with a graph of the difference between line voltage and cap voltage. Even though the graph flattens out, the current still keeps rising (quite significantly since that's really zoomed in). How can the current keep rising when voltage is constant?

Comment: @tgun926 in short it can't keep rising if the voltage is constant as per your ideal scenario so you are either mistaken or something is wrong in your simulation. Basically, current into a cap is \$C\dfrac{dv}{dt}\$ so if current is still rising there must be an upwards slope on the voltage.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question is "because a rectifier is a non-linear device", but I suppose you want more than that.

With 10 uF cap and a 10 ohm load, basically the cap might as well not be there. The time constant RC (which tells you how fast the capacitor voltage will discharge under load) is about 100 usec. As a result, the line current closely follows the line voltage.

With the 1 F cap, the time constant is about 10 seconds, and once charged the capacitor only discharges a tiny bit during one AC half-cycle, so charging only occurs for a brief period right at peak line voltage. If you reduce the value of your 0.5 ohm resistor you'll see the current spike get narrower and higher.

For the intermediate case, you get an intermediate result. With the capacitor partially discharged, you see the line voltage rise above the capacitor voltage at about 2 msec. The current through the bridge has to simultaneously charge the capacitor and provide the load voltage, so the peak current is higher than the 10 uF case, but since the 0.5 ohm resistor plus the effective resistance of the diodes limits the amount of current available, the spike is wider and lower than the 1 F case.